# How can I stop Outlook from restoring calendar items?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Backstory: I used to be on Team A, and frequently worked with Team B. As a result, I was involved in a number of recurring meetings for both teams.

I am now on Team C, and removed all of those Team A / Team B meetings from my calendar. However, every couple of days they reappear with a message stating that they have been restored because I had previously accepted them. This happens even if I decline the invitation now - the meeting disappears temporarily, then returns a few days later.

Is there anything I can do to convince Outlook that I don't ever want these meetings on my calendar anymore?

Comment: If you have configured more that one device or email client that it could be one of them pushing deleted events back to server

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - not as far as I know. They have our servers locked down so you have to be on the VPN to get e-mail, and the client software for a mobile device costs $10 - and I'm too cheap to spring for it. :)